# Remove node warning (Warning: Closing directory handle on garbage collection)

Tags: warnings, node.js-fs

I want to get rid of this warning, but i didn't find anything on the net and closing the directory gives directory closed error.

Warning: Closing directory handle on garbage collection

If i close manually even:

Error [ERR_DIR_CLOSED]: Directory handle was closed